# Complex integral on curve

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I have to show that this integral is zero, but don't know how to evaluate it.
Consider a closed class $C^1$ curve $c:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ and show that $$\int_a^b\frac{\langle c(t),c'(t) \rangle }{\lVert c(t)\lVert^2}dt=0$$

It is necessary to consider $c$ as a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}$ to write $c(t) = (c_1(t),c_2(t))$, then $\langle c(t),c'(t)\rangle = c_1(t)\cdot c_1'(t)+c_2(t)\cdot c_2'(t)$ and $\lVert c(t)\lVert^2=c_1(t)^2+c_2(t)^2$.

PS: I would know how to evaluate if the denominator was not squared, that is the big problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $f(t):=\log\|c(t)\|$, 
$$f'(t)=\frac{\langle c(t),c'(t)\rangle}{\|c(t)\|^2}.$$

Comment: Is there some way to avoid logs? I'm worried cause none is said about $n(c,0)$ ( number of turns around the origin ).

Comment: @Integral: Here $\|c(t)\|>0$ and $\log:(0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$. If I understand your question clearly, then $c(a)=c(b)$ and hence $f(a)=f(b)$. By the way, I think your question has nothing to do with complex analysis.

Comment: indeed, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Integral: You are welcome!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Thank you.